Databricks notebook turns off on long running function activated by ipywidgetds button
I have a long-running function that is triggered by the on_click() method of an ipywidgets button in a Databricks notebook.
I've noticed that the cell is marked as "completed" as soon as the button is displayed. After I click the button to execute the analysis, the function seems to run in the background. However, I believe Databricks interprets this as the cluster being idle. As a result, if the function runs longer than the idle timeout, the cluster shuts down in the middle of execution.
Here is the code I am using:
import threading
import os
import gc
import psutil
from ipywidgets import FloatProgress, widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

# Function to print memory usage
def print_memory_usage():
    process = psutil.Process()
    mem_info = process.memory_info()
    print(f"Memory Usage: {mem_info.rss / (1024 ** 2)} MB")

def run_check_wells_data():
    # Set correct working directory
    global wells_id
    global wells_id_with_data

    with check_wells_output:
        clear_output()
        print('Checking data for wells: ' + str(wells_id))
        
        # Instantiate the bar
        bar = FloatProgress(min=0.0, max=1.0, value=0.01, description='Progress:')
        # Display the bar
        display(bar)

        # Create a dict {well: False}. it will become True if check on data is passed
        mudlog_dict = {well:False for well in wells_id}
        
        # Bool variables
        warning = False
        
        try:
            for well in wells_id:
                print(f"Processing well: {well}")
                print_memory_usage()
                mudlog_db = MudlogDataFrame(get_mudlog_data(well_code=well, dbutils=dbutils))
                
                # Check for duplicates indices, keeping the first
                mudlog_db['DATTIM_UTC'] = mudlog_db.index
                mudlog_db.drop_duplicates(subset=['DATTIM_UTC'], keep='first', inplace=True)
                
                mudlog_db = postprocess_mudlog_data(mud_df=mudlog_db)
                
                if len(mudlog_db) == 0:
                    print('Well ' + well + ': no data available')
                    warning = True  
                else:
                    mudlog_dict.update({well:True})
            
                # Signal to increment the progress bar
                bar.value += (1 / len(wells_id))

                # Explicitly delete the data frame and collect garbage
                del mudlog_db
                gc.collect()
                print_memory_usage()
                
            if warning:
                bar.bar_style = 'warning'
                bar.description = 'Done'
            else:
                bar.bar_style = 'success'
                bar.description = 'Done'
            
            # Wells with data
            wells_id_with_data = [well for well,value in mudlog_dict.items() if value == True]
            print('\n')
            print('Checks on data passed for wells: ' + str(wells_id_with_data))
            # Wells with no data
            wells_id_without_data = [well for well,value in mudlog_dict.items() if value == False]
            print('Checks on data not passed for wells: ' + str(wells_id_without_data))
            print('\n')
            print('Alarms generation will be performed on wells: ' + str(wells_id_with_data))
        
        except TTransportException as tte:
            print('A kinit error has occurred.')
            print(tte)
            print('Please contact the technical support')
            
            bar.bar_style = 'danger'
            bar.description ='Error'
            
        except Exception as e:
            print('An error has occurred, please try again')
            print(e)
            bar.bar_style = 'warning'
            bar.description ='Error'
            
        bar.value = 1

def check_wells_data(ev):
    # Disable the button to avoid continuous clicks
    ev.disabled = True
    
    # Run the long-running process in a separate thread
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_check_wells_data)
    thread.start()
    
    # Re-enable the button after thread starts
    ev.disabled = False

button = widgets.Button(description='Check wells data')
button.on_click(check_wells_data)
display(button)

check_wells_output = widgets.Output()
display(check_wells_output)

This is the cell I execute in the notebook. After the cell is launched, it immediately shows as completed, and the function runs in the background. I suspect that this causes Databricks to see the cluster as idle, and if the function runs past the idle timeout, the cluster shuts off mid-execution:

I need someone's help to solve this problem.
